# Using the debugging features of pyCharm from the command line

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

So I'm trying to debug some python code in pyCharm, and I'm wondering how to do this from the command line, where I can specify inputs.  For example, say I want to execute the following:

```
python pacman.py -l mediumMaze -p SearchAgent -a fn=bfs
```

I can't simply click the debug button in pyCharm, as that just runs the main method without the extra specifications. Could someone suggest a way to run this command inside pyCharm so I can use the debugging feature?

Comment: you can define the Debug config in Pycharm, which gives you the option to define the command line options.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually set a debug configuration in PyCharm:

[image]
[image]